# Only one expression can be specified

Tags: sql-server

Hi when am trying to get the result MSDB and my local DB DXSH using the below query. 
I am getting error message

*"Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."*

```
select (SELECT StoreID FROM dxsh..Store),(select distinct j.Name as "Job Name",h.run_date as LastStatusDate,case h.run_status 
when 0 then 'Failed' 
when 1 then 'Successful' 
when 3 then 'Cancelled' 
when 4 then 'Executing' 
end as JobStatus
from msdb.dbo.sysJobHistory h, msdb.dbo.sysJobs j
where j.job_id = h.job_id and h.run_date = (select max(hi.run_date) from msdb.dbo.sysJobHistory hi where h.job_id = hi.job_id)
and h.run_status = 0
and J.name = 'Clear Trays and Trolleys')
```

Result Expected considering Storeid : 111

111 Clear Trays and Trolleys    20141119    Failed

Please help

Comment: this is wrong: `select (SELECT StoreID FROM dxsh..Store),...` should be something like `select storeID,...` then have the table `Store` in the `from` and join it with other tables `sysJobs` and `sysJobsHistory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving dxsh..store to from should fix the problem, but you need to use some join with other tables.

```
select distinct S.StoreID, j.Name as "Job Name",h.run_date as LastStatusDate,case h.run_status 
when 0 then 'Failed' 
when 1 then 'Successful' 
when 3 then 'Cancelled' 
when 4 then 'Executing' 
end as JobStatus
from msdb.dbo.sysJobHistory h, msdb.dbo.sysJobs j, dxsh..Store S
where j.job_id = h.job_id and h.run_date = (select max(hi.run_date) from msdb.dbo.sysJobHistory hi where h.job_id = hi.job_id)
and h.run_status = 0
and J.name = 'Clear Trays and Trolleys'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select only one column in the second nested query in Select clause in case you are not using exists. If the table dxsh..store has a relation with dbo.sysJobHistory and dbo.sysJobs you can remove the first nested Select and directly select the column. Then the second nested Select clause can be removed.

```
 select distinct str.StoreID, j.Name as "Job Name",h.run_date as LastStatusDate,case h.run_status 
    when 0 then 'Failed' 
    when 1 then 'Successful' 
    when 3 then 'Cancelled' 
    when 4 then 'Executing' 
    end as JobStatus
    from msdb.dbo.sysJobHistory h, msdb.dbo.sysJobs j, dxsh..Store str
    where j.job_id = h.job_id 
    and str.StorID = j.StoreID
    h.run_date = (select max(hi.run_date) from msdb.dbo.sysJobHistory hi where h.job_id = hi.job_id)
    and h.run_status = 0
    and J.name = 'Clear Trays and Trolleys'
```